# How to play audio one after another in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, media

Im very new to WP development...

using following code to play an audio

```
<MediaElement x:Name="MediaSound" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="76,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"  Visibility="Collapsed" Source="/sounds/build.wav" />
```

I need to change the source of media element dynamically.. Lets assume i have 10 audio file and i want to play it one after another...

For that i want to know when the audio is stopped .  Is there any listener available like in android  OnCompletionListener...

I want some thing like this...

```
private void genarateSound(){
     MediaSound.Source = new Uri(audioPath[counter], UriKind.Relative);
     MediaSound.Play();


     //Just to say  
     MediaSound.Oncomplete+ = new OnComplete(AudioPlayComplete); //listen to audio Complete   *Somthing like this*
     }

    //Code segment to execute when audio is stopped
      AudioPlayComplete
     {

        counter++;
        genarateSound();

     }
```

Any help is much appriciated.. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`MediaEnded`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.mediaended%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event will fire when the media reaches the end.

Comment: i included  MediaEnded .. but it never get called

Answer (score 0):

View the following code sample to see how to call and use MediaEnded:

[WP7 background music play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814908/wp7-background-music-play/13826871#13826871)